# Exceeds maximum number of OpenCore instances in android

Tags: android-emulator

when i run my application it shows "Exceeds maximum number of OpenCore instances" error.How to resolve this error.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above happens if your instantianting multiple instances of the MediaPlayer.

You should read about [the lifecycle of the media player and its different states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

- Define one media player, at class variable scope for example
- Instantiate it in the Oncreate method and in the OnResume methods as required
- in your function to play your audio use the .reset method to get the media player to go into and idle state
- use the .setDataSource or equivalent to get it into an initialised state
- then .prepare for the prepared state
- then .start to play the audio
- .stop() etc to stop it
- when your finished use the .release function to release the audio resource.

Media Player is defined as a class scope variable and instantiated in the OnCreate() Method

```
    private void startPlayingAudio()
{
    try {

        Uri path1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.yourpackagehere./" + R.raw.beep);         
        mp.reset();  // reset to idle state
        mp.setDataSource(this, path1); // from idle to initialised state

        mp.prepare();

        mp.start();         
    } catch (Exception ioe) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error playing the beep sound");
    }
}
```